# daemonizing a python script: What is better? start-stop-daemon or python-daemon

Tags: python, linux, daemon

I like to start a python program as a daemon. I checked a bit the internet and came up with two solutions.

The first one is to use [start-stop-daemon](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html) on something like this

```
#!/bin/sh
start() {
    start-stop-daemon -S -q -m -b -p /var/run/sample.pid --exec /usr/bin/python /bin/sample.py && echo "OK" || echo "Failed"
}

stop() {
    start-stop-daemon -K -q -p /var/run/sample.pid
}

case "${1}" in
    start)
        start
        echo "sample service started"
        ;;

    stop)
        stop
        echo "sample service stopped"
        ;;

    restart)
        stop
        start
        echo "sample service restarted"
        ;;

    *)
        echo "usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
        ;;
esac
```

The second one is to use [python-daemon](https://pypi.org/project/python-daemon/)

so I guess we have an extra python file - lets name it "sampleDaemon.py"

```
import daemon
import sample

with daemon.DaemonContext():
    sample()
```

And a bash script (I am not sure about that - I guess this way):

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/python /bin/sampleDeamon.py
```

What is the best way to do it? What are the limitations? The python-deamon documentation is not that big(or I didn't found it).

Comment: Almost all big Linux distributions use systemd nowadays, which takes all the daemonization stuff off your hands. See e.g. https://wiki.debian.org/systemd/Services

Comment: valid comment - as I am building a minimal linux via buildroot I am only start at boot some own services via S99xxx (system V).